# Find the arc length of $f(x)=4x^\frac{1}{2}+9$

Tags: calculus, integration, arc-length

Question:

> If the arc length formula of a function $f$ on an interval $[a,b]$ is given by $L_a^b=\int_a^b \sqrt{1+[f'(x)]^2} \ dx$. Find the arc length of $f(x)=4x^\frac{1}{2}+9$ on $[0,1]$.

We have $[f'(x)]^2=[2x^\frac{-1}{2}]^2=\frac{4}{x}$. Then,

$$L_0^1=\int_0^1 \sqrt{1+\frac{4}{x}} \ dx=\int_0^1 \sqrt{\frac{x+4}{x}} \ dx = \int_0^1 \frac{\sqrt{x+4}}{\sqrt{x}} \ dx=\int_0^1 (x+4)^\frac{1}{2} \ x^\frac{-1}{2} dx$$

I am stuck at this integral, I tried change of variable but it didn't work. Any suggestions? Thanks!

Comment: Integral-calc suggests just using $u = \sqrt{1 + \frac{4}{x}}.$ See here: https://www.integral-calculator.com/#expr=sqrt%281%20%2B%204%2Fx%29

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $u = \sqrt{1 + \frac{4}{x}}$, $x= \frac{4}{u^2-1}$

$\frac{du}{dx} = \frac{-2}{x^2 \cdot\sqrt{1 + \frac{4}{x}} }$

$dx = - \frac{x^2 \cdot\sqrt{1 + \frac{4}{x}}} {2}du 
=- \frac{8u}{(u^2-1)^2} du$

$\sqrt{1 + \frac{4}{x}} dx = - \frac{8u^2}{(u^2-1)^2} du$

$I=\int\limits_{\sqrt{5}}^{\infty} \frac{8u^2}{(u^2-1)^2} du$

Then just use partial fraction to compute this integral.

Answer (score 2):

*Sometimes,* if the arc-length integrand for a function looks troublesome (or hopeless) in one variable, the inverse function may be easier to deal with.  For $ \ y \ = \ 4\sqrt{x} \ + \ 9 \ \   $ on $ \ [0 \ , \ 1] \ \ , $ that inverse would be $ \ x \ = \ \left(\frac{y \ - \ 9}{4} \right)^2 \ \ $ on $ \ [9 \ , \ 13] \ \ . \ $  The arc-length integral becomes $$ \ \int_9^{13} \ \sqrt{ \ \left(\frac{dx}{dy} \right)^2 \ + \ 1} \ \ dy \ \ $$

and we obtain by implicit differentiation $ \ \frac{d}{dy} [ \ y \ ] \ = \ \frac{d}{dy} [ \ 4·x^{1/2} + 9 \ ] \ \Rightarrow \ 1 \ = \ 2·x^{-1/2}·\frac{dx}{dy} $ $ \Rightarrow \ \frac{dx}{dy} \ = \ \frac{\sqrt{x}}{2} \ \ . \ $  The integral is now
$$ \ \int_9^{13} \ \sqrt{ \ \left(\frac{\sqrt{x}}{2} \right)^2 \ + \ 1} \ \ dy \ \ = \ \ \int_9^{13} \ \sqrt{ \  \frac{ x \ + \ 4}{4} } \ \ dy $$ $$ = \ \  \ \int_9^{13} \ \sqrt{ \     \frac{[ \ (y \ - \ 9)^2 \ / \ 4^2 \ ] \ + \ 4}{4}    } \ \ dy $$
$$ = \ \ \frac12·\frac14 \ \int_9^{13} \ \sqrt{ \     (y \ - \ 9)^2 \ + \ 64     } \ \ dy \ \ \rightarrow_{u \ = \ y - 9} \ \ \frac18 \ \int_0^4 \ \sqrt{ \     u^2 \ + \ 64     } \ \ du \ \ , $$
which now at least looks like a more familiar integral if you've worked with trigonometric substitutions.

[Note, incidentally, that this is an *improper* integral (of the type where the integrand is undefined somewhere on the interval of integration).  We see, however, that it does "converge" to a finite value.]

Comment: Good answer, it looks easier for me to compute by letting $u=8tan(\theta)$ than computing the partial fractions.

Comment: @Tim  It may be easier to manipulate, but the final evaluation gives the same "messy" result as that of everyone else's answers.  Your method is interesting in that it transforms the character of the improper integral to one with an "endpoint at infinity".

Answer (score 1):

$I= \int_0^1 \frac{\sqrt {x+4}}{\sqrt x}\, dx$

Put $\frac{\sqrt {x+4}}{\sqrt x}=u$

$I = \int_2^{\sqrt5} \frac{8
}{u^4-2u^2+1}\,du$

you can use partial fractions and proceed from here

$I={2}\ln(\frac{ \sqrt {x+4} + \sqrt x}{\sqrt {x+4}}) - {2}\ln(\frac{ \sqrt {x+4} - \sqrt x}{\sqrt {x+4}}) + \sqrt x \sqrt{x+4}$

putting the bounds;

$I=2 {\ln(\sqrt5+1)-2\ln(\sqrt5-1)+\sqrt5} \approx 4.2$

Comment: There is some mistakes in third line I=$\int ... du$, use change of variables, integrate for du is not from u=0,1.

Comment: The evaluation of the correct anti-derivative function will need to be handled carefully since the original integral is improper, so your transformed integral has one integration "endpoint" at $ \ +\infty \ \ . $

Comment: @Tim thank you pointing that out